# Javascript "Undefined is not an object" when an object is defined?

Tags: javascript, debugging, null, undefined

When selecting an ID or ClassName in Javascript it does not work. The class or ID does exist and is spelled correctly. Why does Javascript tell me that **Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'header.style.height = ""')** while the object is defined properly? The script below is just a plain example, but I can't select (almost) anything. No matter what ID or class I select. I know that it says it can't find the object, but why?

```
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 128 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 128) {
      header.style.height = "48px";
    } else {
      header.style.height = "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try adding a `defer` attribute to script tag. Cause this script might be running before the DOM content is loaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer

Comment: Put the variable declaration inside `scrollFunction`

Comment: I went to your website and couldn't find `window.onscroll` in the JS. Which file is it in?

Comment: @Barmar I had removed the script but it's on the site now.

Comment: The script using `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementById`. Since that returns a list, you have to index it. `var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];`

Comment: Or use `var header = document.querySelector(".header");`

Comment: There's no `id="header"` anywhere in the document, why would you expect that to work?

Comment: @Barmar Ahh, indexing it worked! Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to maybe change `var header = document.getElementById("header")`
to `var header = document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0]`
because i saw in your website that there is a div with a class name of "header" and you need to add the [0] to select the first element of the node list returned from getElementsByClassName.

Comment: You need to index it, since `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried both giving the header an ID and using it, and its existing ClassName. Both give me the same Undefined message.

Comment: Make sure your script is at the end of the HTML, or in `$(document).ready()`